# Get an error when trying to get all the photos from PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections

Tags: swift, photosframework

I want to get all the photos of my custom album.
but instead what I get is the below error.

**My Code**

```
let collections:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
```

**Error i get**

> "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7
>   "(null)""

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: add first `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Descriptionkey` in your info.plist and then try to run this code

Comment: that was my first thought too, but I already set that.
`let authState = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()`
-> authorized

Comment: `swift` and `Xcode` version?

Comment: Xcode Version 11.0 beta 6 (11M392r)
Swift 5

Comment: @BjörnLindner Could you confirm if it happens on non beta version of Xcode like Xcode 10.2?

Comment: I can confirm this on Xcode 11, running on a device that has iCloud photos enabled. Thinking that's the culprit, but I don't know how to fix it yet.

Comment: Hey @chirag90, did you manage to find a fix?

Comment: I'm getting this error printed in the terminal but the `PHAssets` are being correctly retrieved. When I try to call the `PHImageManager().requestImage` in Xcode11 though, I need to specify `options.deliveryMode  = .highQualityFormat`, while it used to work just fine with `.fastFormat` back in Xcode10.

Comment: @BjörnLindner By any chance were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I am having a similar problem when I am calling for all the photos as well. I thought it might be because of the large number of images in my library and reduced it using the fetchlimit parameter. Unfortunately didn't make a difference. I am looking for a solution. Has anyone solved this yet?

Comment: I _can_ get the photos from the library (videos, in my case) but I still get this "Error" (effectively, a _warning_) on the console...

Comment: I can get the photos from the library but I still get this "Error" (effectively, a warning) on the console... +1

Comment: I have the same error on Xcode version 11.5

Comment: Has someone managed to solve this issue? please share...

Comment: This doesn't actually stop you from fetching the assets. It could be a bug on Apple's side - file it on Feedback Assistant.app.

Comment: It seems this error was coming when I was trying to do this task:
Context: I have 4 images which i need to archive from Application Folder in user domain to a new Gallery of my choosing.
Task: Started trying to create the Custom Gallery in each function call to archive a single photo.
Root cause: Multiple threads doing the same task at the same time. Dead lock !

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, I'm not entirely sure what the issue is but I hope this code could provide some assistance. Using .album rather than .smartAlbum could also be part of the issue.

```
private var fetchResult: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!

func fetchOptions(_ predicate: NSPredicate?) -> PHFetchOptions {
            let options = PHFetchOptions()
            options.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false) ]
        options.predicate = predicate
        return options
    }
}

    if let userLibraryCollection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .smartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil).firstObject {
        self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: userLibraryCollection, options: fetchOptions(NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = \(PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)")))
    } else {
        self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions(nil))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private var fetchResult: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!
    
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking 
 results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    
    if let userLibraryCollection = 
 PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: 
 .smartAlbumUserLibrary, options: nil).firstObject {
        
        self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: 
     userLibraryCollection, options: fetchOptions(NSPredicate(format: 
     "mediaType = \(PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)")))
        
        fetchResult.enumerateObjects { asset, index, stop in
            PHAsset.getURL(ofPhotoWith: asset) { (url) in
                
                if let imgurl = url{
                    print(imgurl)
                }else {
                    print("error")
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
        
        
    } else {
        self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: 
     fetchOptions(nil))
        
        print(fetchResult.firstObject)
    }
}



  extension PHAsset {
static func getURL(ofPhotoWith mPhasset: PHAsset, completionHandler : @escaping ((_ responseURL : URL?) -> Void)) {
    if mPhasset.mediaType == .image {
        let options: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
        options.canHandleAdjustmentData = {(adjustmeta: PHAdjustmentData) -> Bool in
            return true
        }
        mPhasset.requestContentEditingInput(with: options, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, info) in
            if let fullSizeImageUrl = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL {
                completionHandler(fullSizeImageUrl)
            } else {
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        })
    } else if mPhasset.mediaType == .video {
        let options: PHVideoRequestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
        options.version = .original
        PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: mPhasset, options: options, resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) in
            if let urlAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                let localVideoUrl = urlAsset.url
                completionHandler(localVideoUrl)
            } else {
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        })
       }
    
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do everything with `PHAsset` on the main thread. I still get that error, but at least images are fetched.

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.includeHiddenAssets = false
options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)] // Newest first
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = \(PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)") // Only images

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.mediaAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)
}
```